# Why strstr() - char pointer = number?

Tags: c++, pointers, strstr

I have this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char char1[30] = "ExtraCharacter", char2[30] = "Character", *p;

  p = strstr(char1, char2);
  cout << "p: " << p << endl;
  cout << "char1: " << char1 << endl;
  cout << "(p-char1): " << (p-char1) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get:

```
p: Character
char1: ExtraCharacter
(p-char1): 5
```

as expected.

But this is not the problem, I'm not sure why `"Character" - "ExtraCharacter"` is an integer (5)? Perhaps not an integer, but a number/digit anyways.
Actually I don't understand why is "Character" stored in `p`, and not the memory address.

If I understood well from a book, `strstr()` returns a **memory address**, shouldn't it be more like a strange value, like a hex (0x0045fe00) or something like that? I mean, it's `cout << p` not `cout << *p` to display the actual value of that memory address.

Can someone explain me how it works?

P.S.: I apologize if the title is not that coherent.

Comment: In `p-char1` both `p` and and `char1` act as pointers. You can subtract pointers in C++.

Comment: @AnT, I don't understand why the value of `p` without the asterisk is not a memory address, somelike like a hex value when it is displayed with `cout`.

Comment: @ShadowXsc `p` is a memory address.  It is a pointer to `char`.  The question is more  like "why does a `char *` print as a string rather than an address?"

Comment: You need to validate that `p != NULL` or you will have a very unpleasant surprise if no substring `char2` is found in `char1`...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin this program was only for test purposes, in the book, there is a if statament for validation. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Comment: Glad you got that point, you would not believe the number of questions that come by where *validation* is a foreign concept -- resulting in no end of SegFaults due to unintentional `NULL` pointer use `:)`

Comment: To get p to print as an address, cast it to a `(void*)p`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But this is not the problem, I'm not sure why "Character" - "ExtraCharacter" is an integer (5)?

You subtract one pointer from another and result - number, distance from `char` `char1` points to to `char` `p` points to. This is how pointer arithmetic works.

Note: this subtraction is only valid when both pointers point to the same array (or behind the last element), which is the case in your code, but you need to be careful. For example if `strstr()` does not find susbtring then it would return `nullptr` and your subtraction will have UB. So at least check `p` before subtracting (and passing `nullptr` to `std::cout` would have UB as well)

> If I understood well from a book, strstr() returns a memory address, shouldn't it be more like a strange value, like a hex (0x0045fe00) or something like that? I mean, it's cout << p not cout << *p to display the actual value of that memory address.

Yes `p` is a pointer aka memory adress. `std::ostream` has special rule how to print pointers to char - as strings, because strings in C stored that way. If you want to see it as a pointer just cast it:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void *>( p );
```

then you will see it as an address.

Comment: Oh, ok, so there's a rule for the char pointers being displayed as strings with cout. This is what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to mention that this subtraction is UB as the pointers don't belong to the same object/array

Comment: @ShadowXsc right, otherwise you would see address when you write `std::cout << "Hello world!\n";`

Comment: @Slava Oh, that makes sense now when you put the problem in that way.

Answer (score 1):

To display address, you have to cast `char*` to `void*`:

```
std::cout << "p: " << static_cast<const void*>(p) << std::endl;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/g8lESh)

Answer (score 1):

For std::basic_ostream (type of cout), character and character string arguments (e.g., of type char or const char*) are handled by the non-member overloads of operator<< which are being treated as strings. char[30] will be decayed to const char* argument and basic_ostream will output the null terminated string at the address of the pointer.

As for (p-char1), the result of subtracting two pointers is a std::ptrdiff_t. It is an implementation-defined signed integer. That's why the output is 5